# Can this simple percentage calculator be further optimized?

Tags: java, optimization

```
public double getValueWithPercentage(double number, double percentage)
{
    return number + ((percentage / 100.0) * number);
}
```

Are there any tricks to optimize this simple code?

Comment: What lead you to believe that this method may need optimising?

Comment: are you talking about performance optimization, or precision increase? which are the variable ranges?

Comment: I think it's worth noting a few things. 1. Multiplication is faster than division. 2. Bitshifting, or Bitwise operations, will not be faster since [most compilers perform this for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net) 3. Unless you are working with VERY large numbers, aka BigInteger, you won't see improvements with multiplication algorithms like [Schönhage–Strassen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since floating-point divide is sometimes a little slower than multiply (and never faster, AFAIK), I'd write your function like this:

```
public double getValueWithPercentage(double number, double percentage)
{
    return number * (1 + percentage * 0.01);
}
```